# Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() - setListAdapter

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm trying to call setListAdapter in android from inside a thread to show a list. I know that I can't acces Android UI from outside a UI thread, so I'm using runOnUiThread, but I still get the exception: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare(). Can anyone tell me why and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
 public void checkLoginInformation(View view)
    { client_th = new Thread( new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    cs = new Socket("192.168.0.101",2014);
                    final DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());
                    final DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(cs.getInputStream());
                    String msg = is.readUTF();
                    if(msg.equals("logat"))
                    {
                       final ShowList l = new ShowList();
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                l.show();
                            }
                        });
                     }
                 }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        client_th.start();
    }
```

The ShowList class:

```
public class ShowList extends ListActivity
{
    private final String [] online_drivers = {"one","two","three"};
    private final Context context = this;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.online_window);
    }

    public void show()
    {

       setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                online_drivers));

    }
}
```

And the exception I get:

```
03-12 08:22:03.096    1895-1914/com.example.irinab.licenta2 W/System.err﹕ java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
03-12 08:22:03.096    1895-1914/com.example.irinab.licenta2 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
03-12 08:22:03.096    1895-1914/com.example.irinab.licenta2 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
03-12 08:22:03.096    1895-1914/com.example.irinab.licenta2 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:765)
03-12 08:22:03.096    1895-1914/com.example.irinab.licenta2 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ListActivity.<init>(ListActivity.java:175)
03-12 08:22:03.096    1895-1914/com.example.irinab.licenta2 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.irinab.licenta2.ShowList.<init>(ShowList.java:14)
03-12 08:22:03.096    1895-1914/com.example.irinab.licenta2 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.irinab.licenta2.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:120)
03-12 08:22:03.096    1895-1914/com.example.irinab.licenta2 W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `final ShowList l = new ShowList();`  is not how you're supposed to start a new Activity.
For starting your `ShowList` Activity, do this :

```
Intent startShowListIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowList.class);
startActivity(startShowListIntent);
```

In the above snippet, I'm assuming the name of your current activity to be `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
final ShowList l = new ShowList();
```

Creating Object of `ShowList` Activity to show ListView by calling `show` method.

Use `startActivity` for starting `ShowList` Activity:

```
intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                    ShowList.class);
view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```